# Stripping HTML from a column WITHOUT using a function?

Tags: sql-server

Basically I had an error in my code that was causing entries to save to the database with HTML in there. I corrected the code so all future entries will be correct but I wanted to run through the database once and correct all the previous ones. I found this function on this forum to do this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_StripHTML] (@HTMLText VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX) AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Start INT
DECLARE @End INT
DECLARE @Length INT
SET @Start = CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText)
SET @End = CHARINDEX('>',@HTMLText,CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText))
SET @Length = (@End - @Start) + 1
WHILE @Start > 0 AND @End > 0 AND @Length > 0
BEGIN
    SET @HTMLText = STUFF(@HTMLText,@Start,@Length,'')
    SET @Start = CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText)
    SET @End = CHARINDEX('>',@HTMLText,CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText))
    SET @Length = (@End - @Start) + 1
END
```

However I wanted to do this without creating a function since I'm only using this once, and the DBA does not want me to put anything in the database. How could I get this to work outside of the UDF? I'm not too familiar with SQL.

My code:

```
Update [OrderItem]
set [Description] = --??? Description without the HTML
from [Order] o inner join [OrderItem] oi on o.OrderID = oi.OrderID
```

Comment: A string of ugly Replace() brackets stripping out the most common tags? i.e. `Replace(Replace(Replace([Description],'<HTML>',''),'<br>',''),'</html>','')

Comment: ^ you're still using a function though :D

Comment: @DanyKhalife, yes, but it's not a UDF that's stored in the database. That's the important thing.

Comment: Ah ok i misunderstood the question, makes sense now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can easily work simply by removing CREATE FUNCTION tag. Try running this in SSMS yourself.

```
DECLARE @HTMLText VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @HTMLText = '<html><head><title>this is title</title></head><body>this is text</body></html>'

DECLARE @Start INT
DECLARE @End INT
DECLARE @Length INT
SET @Start = CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText)
SET @End = CHARINDEX('>',@HTMLText,CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText))
SET @Length = (@End - @Start) + 1
WHILE @Start > 0 AND @End > 0 AND @Length > 0
BEGIN
    SET @HTMLText = STUFF(@HTMLText,@Start,@Length,'')
    SET @Start = CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText)
    SET @End = CHARINDEX('>',@HTMLText,CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText))
    SET @Length = (@End - @Start) + 1
END

select @HTMLText
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never done this before, but if I had to, here's the ugly alternative. First, dump your data into a temp table @Tmp.  Then, use a series of update statements:

```
Update @Tmp set Description=Replace(Description,'<html>','')
Update @Tmp set Description=Replace(Description,'</html>','')
Update @Tmp set Description=Replace(Description,'<table>','')
Update @Tmp set Description=Replace(Description,'</table>','')
```

This will be *relatively* easy to maintain/add/remove tags.  Since they are all explicitly defined, the hardest part would be knowing in advance what needs to be stripped.